# Fazer PageFooter com tamanho dinâmico no iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, jasper, relatório

Ao criar um relatório no `iReport` e gostaria que o `PageFooter` tivesse seu tamanho dinâmico de acordo com os componentes que estivessem visíveis dentro dele.

Nem todos os componentes do `PageFooter` estarão visíveis em todas as páginas e também outros não irão aparecer dependendo da configuração do relatório, esses componentes normalmente compoẽm uma linha inteira, que não deveria ocupar espaço no relatório caso estivesse em branco.

Já tentei utilizar o parâmetro `Remove Line When Blank` mas no PageFooter não surte efeito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o `PageFooter` não é possível ter um tamanho dinâmico devido a limitação do próprio `iReport`, no meu caso o que fiz para resolver foi desenvolver toda a primeira página no `Title` controlando com subrelatórios o que deveria ou não aparecer assim como a quantidade de informações, depois as outras páginas seguiram a estrutura normal do `iReport`, no meu caso resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, cara, minha dica é pra você criar `Groups` de acordo com cada linha da qual você tem que exibir(para ficar mais organizado) ou `Details` podendo manter seu `PageFooter`. Você só precisará adicionar uma expressão em `Print When Expression` para dizer quando o `Group`, `Detail` ou mesmo o `PageFooter` irá aparecer. Veja o exemplo na imagem abaixo:
[image: Breve exemplo, pode ser feito da mesma maneira para os <code>Details</code>]

Tome cuidado quando for selecionar seu `Group`, `Detail` ou `PageFooter`, para não clicar em algum `TextField`, `Labels`, `List`, `etc`. pois os mesmo tem as mesma propriedades.

Comment: A ideia é boa Julio Cesar o problema é que não consigo imprimir o GroupFooter exatamente no fim da primeira página.